# How to use Crashlytics with RoboVM iOS binding?

Tags: java, libgdx, crashlytics, robovm

I'm trying to connect Crashlytics to my LibGDX project using [RoboVM iOS bindings](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings). I followed instructions from bindings web page: downloaded jar-file, put it in `libs`, modified `build.gradle`, synced... I also added `<frameworks>` from `robovm.xml` of the binding to my `robovm.xml` (not sure if it's needed for my gradle configuration).

I added `Crashlytics.start()` method call in my `IOSLauncher` class:

```
public class IOSLauncher extends IOSApplication.Delegate {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean didFinishLaunching(UIApplication application, UIApplicationLaunchOptions launchOptions) {
        Crashlytics.start("myAPIkeyIsHere");
        return super.didFinishLaunching(application, launchOptions);
    }
    ...
}
```

It's a little bit different from [sample](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/blob/master/crashlytics/src/org/robovm/bindings/crashlytics/sample/Sample.java) because my `IOSLauncher` class extends `IOSApplication.Delegate` not `UIApplicationDelegateAdapter`. But I think this doesn't matter.

After that I'm trying to force crash my app. I added `throw new RuntimeException()` at the start of my core project. App is successfully crashing. I can see corresponding stacktrace in console but I don't get any crash logs in Crashlytics dashboard.

I searched Crashlytics knowledge base and found that XCode may hide crash information from Crashlytics. So I tried crashing my app on my iPad disconnected from my Mac but it didn't help.

I googled a lot but there is almost no information about usage of this bindings with Crashlytics. Does anybody can help me with this? How can I check that Crashlytics connected correctly to my project? May be I forget something?

P.S. Earlier I connected Crashlytics to Android backend of the same project and it works fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crashlytics does not work with roboVM at the moment, as far as I know. [Here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=11145&p=69109&hilit=crashlytics#p69109) is a post with a contributor saying as much. There is also some info [here](https://github.com/robovm/robovm/issues/215) where the contributors say they are not supporting mach exception handling at the moment, which crashlytics uses.

You can use Bugsense or Flurry as alternatives though.

Comment: Has anything changed about Crashlytics not working with roboVM?

Comment: Seems to be still not working. Firebase Crash Reporting is also not working currently. Will have to check one of the alternatives listed above.